# Default Gateway is not detected in Rhel server after ifdown of primary network interface

Tags: linux, networking, centos, routing, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm working on RHEL 7.6 server.
I've configured network using bonding with active backup mode.
So the eno1 is the primary interface of bond0 and eno4 is the slave of bond0.
this is the configuration of bond0

```
[root@xufrtrihpdb01 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
PEERDNS=no
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERROUTES=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_PEERDNS=no
IPV6_PEERROUTES=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=bond0
#UUID=d390806d-94a8-4648-8d26-b9c79b0dacd7
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=10.27.45.73
PREFIX=25
GATEWAY=10.27.45.1
#TYPE=bond
TYPE=Ethernet
BONDING_MASTER=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=1 miimon=1000 primary=eno1"
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

the config of eno1

```
[root@xufrtrihpdb01 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eno1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=no
PEERDNS=no
PEERROUTES=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_PEERDNS=no
IPV6_PEERROUTES=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eno1
#UUID=d390806d-94a8-4648-8d26-b9c79b0dacd7
DEVICE=eno1
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

the config of eno4

```
[root@xufrtrihpdb01 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eno4
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=no
PEERDNS=no
PEERROUTES=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_PEERDNS=no
IPV6_PEERROUTES=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eno4
#UUID=734fcafd-d2ac-4983-83a4-0fa365986286
DEVICE=eno4
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Here, everything works well. Ping to default gateway and external traffic works.  But if I run

```
Ifdown eno1
```

The bond basculate to eno4 as a primary. But ping to default gateway and exxternal traffic doesn't work. It looks like "eno4" doesn't take the default gateway of bond0
Remark : I didn't add any file of static routes

Comment: I am by no means an expert when it comes to Linux NIC bonding/teaming, but your config files look a bit different than the ones on this tutorial I found, namely, the number of options in your two slave interfaces and the fact that `TYPE=Bond` is commented out in your master interface: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-create-an-interface-bonding-nic-teaming-using-nmcli/

Comment: @SamForbis , I think that the problem doesn't come from the Type. I test it with type=Bond and it doesn't work :/ :/

Comment: Does it work if you have `eno4` set as primary though? What exactly do you mean by not work anyway? (As in, what do you get from ping?)

Comment: @TomYan, when I set eno4 as a primary, It doesn't work also . When I ping Default gateway or external Host it displays : Host unreachable

Comment: What are the two interfaces physically connected to respectively anyway?

Comment: @TomYan . The two interfaces are directly connected to a Switch with mode access ( the same vlan: XX)

Comment: Maybe you should post `ip a` and `ip r` output. Does `eno4` even work when you are not doing bonding?